# Access .constructor of class defined in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```
export class Entity {
    add(component: Component, componentClass?: { new (): Component;}): Entity {
        if (!componentClass) {
            componentClass = component.constructor
        }

        /** sniiiiip **/
    }
}
```

Line 4 of the example (assigning component.constructor) causes the compiler to complain that:

> The property 'constructor' does not exist on value of type 'Component'

What's the proper way to get a reference to an objects constructor?  My understanding is that all Objects in JavaScript have a .constructor property that points to the constructor used to create that object...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is rare enough in typed code that it's not included by default on the definition of `Object`. You can simply cast to `any` instead:

```
componentClass = (<any>component).constructor;
```