# Default constructable class types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use a [TypedJSON](https://github.com/JohnWeisz/TypedJSON) function with this signature:

```
parse<T>(text: string, type: {
    new (): T;
}, settings?: SerializerSettings): T;
```

The function I want does something similar to this:

```
function processJson<T>(json: string, processor: (jsonObject: T) => any): void {
    let t: T;
    let ob = TypedJSON.parse(json, t);
    processor(ob);
}
```

However that doesn't type-check because:

> Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => {}'.

So I add some extra type information:

```
function processJson<T extends { new (): T; }>(json: string, processor: (jsonObject: T) => any): void {
    let t: T;
    let ob = TypedJSON.parse(json, t);
    processor(ob);
}
```

Now that type checks but when I come to use it...

```
@JsonObject
class Foo {
    @JsonMember
    public X: number;
}

processJson<Foo>("{'X': 12}", (f: Foo) => {});
```

... I get this error:

> Type 'Foo' does not satisfy the constraint 'new () => Foo'. Type 'Foo' provides no match for the signature 'new (): Foo'.

Except of course I can do this no problem:

```
let f = new Foo();
```

I'm new to Typescript. Is there some magic incantation I can use to fix this? Or failing that, is there some way I can ignore this type check?

Comment: You can define `interface Foo { new (): Foo; }` alongside class definition

Comment: Yes I tried adding `interface<T> DefaultConstructable { new (): T }` and then `class Foo implements DefaultConstructable<Foo> { ...`. It works but it is a lot of boilerplate to tell the compiler something that it should already know is true.

Comment: No, I mean just add `interface Foo { new (): Foo; }` after `class Foo` definition, that's it. (no need in `class Foo implements...`)

Comment: Ah that works, but that's actually still a lot of boilerplate if I have to do it for every class.

Comment: By the way, generic type info is not available at runtime, so I think you can't use generics here (check if `ob instanceof Foo`).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick by giving up on typing:

```
let ob = TypedJSON.parse(json, t as any);
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598109/access-constructor-of-class-defined-in-typescript).